# Typing and rendering latex in Microsoft Teams meeting chat

Tags: latex, microsoft-teams

I recently found that if you have an equation in Word saved as latex like this:
[image: Microsoft Word with a LaTeX formatted equation]
then copy the equation and paste it into a teams meeting chat it looks like this:
[image: Equation pasted into teams meeting chat]
it actually renders the equation. When it's in my clipboard, it looks like plain text, not an image:
[image: Formatting in the clipboard]

Is there some way to render latex equations natively in Teams meeting chats, without needing to copy from Word?

Comment: Keep in mind that clipboard data can be present in multiple formats simultaneously.

Comment: Is it being pasted unto teams as an image or as formatted "rich" text or other editable form?

Comment: When it's pasted into teams, it takes a bit of time, but eventually loads in an image(that's why I think teams itself is rendering the latex). When it's pasted into other programs that also accept pasting images from the clipboard, it usually pastes the raw latex text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is not a viable feature in MS Teams at the moment, however, [this feature request](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/1079b1df-78bd-ed11-83ff-002248273995?q=latex%20teams) have been moved under review by the MS Teams team.

[MS Teams Latex input request on MS Teams user voice forum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNb2b.png)